# Jolt Transform filter values using another value of the json

Tags: json, formatting, jolt

I have this JSON:

```json
{
  "mapTrue": "true",
  "code": [
    "X",
    "Y",
    "Z"
  ],
  "expired": [
    "true",
    "false",
    "true"
  ]
}
```

I want to use the `"mapTrue"` value in order to filter the `"code"` array.

If `"mapTrue": "true"`, I'll take the `0` and `2` values in "expired" array, therefore I need to output

```json
"code": ["X", "Z"].
```

Using the same logic, for `"mapTrue: "false"` I'll return `"code": ["Y"]`.

This specification returns the right `"code"` array but it doesn't use the `"mapTrue"` value.

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "expired": {
        "*": {
          "true": {
            "@(3,code[&1])": "code"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

That's where my problem is.

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "expired": "@(1,mapTrue)",
      "code": "code"
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": {
          "&1": {
            "@(3,code[&1])": "code[]"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative option would be using the following specs

```json
[
  {
    // separate the values for "true", "false" while match "code" with the value of "mapTrue" 
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "c*": {
        "*": "@(2,expired[&])", // walk through the indexes(0,1,2) of "expired" array while matching with the components of "code"
        "@(1,mapTrue)": "&1"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "c*": {
        "*": {
          "@(2,&)": "&2" // grab the value going tree up two levels by using "@(2,&)", and copy the main object's label "code" by grabbing it after going tree two levels again
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

the ***demo*** on the site http://jolt-demo.appspot.com/ is

[image]